# How to run an XCode iOS app on device via Automatic Signing?

Tags: ios, xcode, developer-program

I'm trying to test a Swift example project on an iOS (17.2.1) de device via XCode (15.2).

I haven't used XCode in about a decade. I remember there was a way to generate a self-signed certificate to load an app on your own device via USB for free using this page: https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/

When I try to access that I see:

> **Access Unavailable**
> This resource is only for developers enrolled in a developer program or members of an organization’s team in a developer program.

[image: screenshot of the the above mentioned URL and Access Unavailable error]

Is it still possible to deploy one's own iOS app on one's own device without paying the developer fee ? If so, how ?

(To clarify this is not a direct question about code, compiling, etc. which is why I haven't posted on stackoverflow. This is a question about the provisioning/self signed certicates/XCode interface/Apple Developer services)